# R mutate across and using two dynamically named columns to calculate result

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
Test <- tribble(~Date, ~HCl_Konz, ~HCl_Kenn, ~CO_Konz, ~CO_Kenn,
                   1, 4, "", 4, "",
                   2, 5, "", 1, "",
                   3, 2, "X", 6, "BX",
                   4, 5, "", 4, "",
                   5, 6, "F", 4, "",
                   6, 5, "", 9, "EXr")
Param <- c("HCl", "CO")
```

The real tibble is much bigger and has several columns like the HCl and CO, but they all follow the same scheme. For all of these columns I want to set the value of HCl_Konz to NA, if the Column HCl_Kenn has at least one of the chars "X" or "F", the same with CO_Konz (if CO_Kenn includes X or F), and all the oder XXX_Konz columns.

I tried the following code, but it quits with the following error.

```
Test %>% rowwise() %>%
    mutate(across(paste(Param, "_Konz", sep=""), ~ ifelse(str_detect(paste(str_sub(cur_column(),1,-6), "_Kenn", sep=""), "[XF]"), NA_real_, .x)))
```

The code doesn't throw an error, but the values are not replaced by NA.

tia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're missing the `~` to mark the `ifelse(..)` as a function of sorts.
2. `cur_col()` not found (for me), should likely be `.` or `.x`
3. You are `str_detect`ing in the name of the `_Kenn`-equivalent column, not the values in that column; we need to add `cur_data()[[..]]` as well.

I tend to not use `stringr` for straight-forward replacements like this, preferring base R:

```r
library(dplyr)
Test %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      paste0(Param, "_Konz"),
      ~ if_else( grepl("[XF]", cur_data()[[ gsub("_Konz", "_Kenn", cur_column()) ]] ),
                .[NA], . )
    )
  )
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#    Date HCl_Konz HCl_Kenn CO_Konz CO_Kenn
#   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>  
# 1     1        4 ""             4 ""     
# 2     2        5 ""             1 ""     
# 3     3       NA "X"           NA "BX"   
# 4     4        5 ""             4 ""     
# 5     5       NA "F"            4 ""     
# 6     6        5 ""            NA "EXr"
```

I recommend `dplyr::if_else` in place of `ifelse` for several reasons, but it comes with the strict (and safe!) requirement that the `true=` and `false=` arguments be precisely the same type. You recognize at least most of this by your use of `NA_real_`; my use of `.[NA]` is another way of ensuring that we get the correct `NA`-variant based on the actual data, allowing this method to work if some of your `Params` are `integer` and some are `numeric`, for example.

An alternative approach (which may help later) is to pivot the data and work with just two columns at a time.

```r
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
Test %>%
  pivot_longer(
    matches("_(Konz|Kenn)$"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("elem", ".value")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Konz = if_else(grepl("[XF]", Kenn), Konz[NA], Konz)
  )
# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#     Date elem   Konz Kenn 
#    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#  1     1 HCl       4 ""   
#  2     1 CO        4 ""   
#  3     2 HCl       5 ""   
#  4     2 CO        1 ""   
#  5     3 HCl      NA "X"  
#  6     3 CO       NA "BX" 
#  7     4 HCl       5 ""   
#  8     4 CO        4 ""   
#  9     5 HCl      NA "F"  
# 10     5 CO        4 ""   
# 11     6 HCl       5 ""   
# 12     6 CO       NA "EXr"
```

This pivoted format has the advantage of allowing simpler calls to `mutate`, and (if you plan on plotting this) playing much better with `ggplot2`'s preference for long data.

Comment: Thanks! I allready realised the errors 1) and 2) and edited my post. But I needed the "cur_data()".
Thanks also for the second way, this is also very interessting.

Comment: I'm glad this worked. If you recognize you have syntax errors in your code, it is really useful for you to fix them so that we aren't parsing through problematic code.

Comment: I tried both versions. First one is faster. Furthermore the second version has a problem, because there are "_Kenn" columns without matching "_Konz" columns.